# when i click the submit button it doesnt goes to the mentioned url. it has no effect in rails. The search fiter isnt working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

This is my search filter form , when i click the submit button it doesn't go to the mentioned url. it has no effect.

```
<%= form_with(url: "user_hotels_path", method: "get") do %>
                            <div class = "form-group">
                              <%= label_tag :num_of_guests, "No of Guests" %>
                              <%= number_field :num_of_guests, @number_guests, placeholder: "Enter no. of guests", class: "form-control"%>
                            </div>
                            <div class = "form-group">
                              <%= label_tag :num_of_rooms, "No of Rooms "%>
                              <%= number_field :num_of_rooms, @number_rooms, placeholder: "Enter no. of rooms", class: "form-control"%>
                            </div>
                            <div class = "form-group">
                              <%= label_tag :check_in_date, "Check IN "%>
                              <%= date_field :check_in_date, placeholder: "Enter check in date", class: "form-control"%>
                            </div>
                            <div class = "form-group">
                              <%= label_tag :check_out_date, "Check Out "%>
                              <%= date_field :check_out_date, placeholder: "Enter check out date", class: "form-control"%>
                            </div>
                            <div class ="form-group">
                                <%= label :city, "city"%>
                                <%= collection_select( :hotel, :city_id, City.all, :id, :name, {}, { multiple: false })%>
                            </div>

                            <div class = "form-group">
                              <%= submit_tag "SUBMIT", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                            </div>
                        <% end %>
```

This the the controller

```
class UserHotelsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_hotel, except:[:index]

    def index
      if params[:num_of_rooms] 
        @number_rooms = params[:num_of_rooms] 
        room = Hotel.equals(@number_rooms)
      else
        @hotels = Hotel.all
      end
    end

    private

    def find_hotel
      @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

This is the model, i am trying to get the results which fetches the total no. of single rooms as per availability and filter those hotels

```
class UserHotel < ApplicationRecord
    def self.equals(number_rooms)
        where ("hotel.room.single_bed = ? ", number_rooms)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just the change in syntax is required.

```
<%= form_tag user_hotels_path, method: get) do %>
```